# Facing an issue while starting a springboot application for practice. Getting issue while starting the application on intellij on mac air

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jpa, logging

I am just trying to start the application on intellij but the issue is coming as above. Checked for dependencies in pom.xml file but all is fine with the log:

Log:

```
2023-12-24T17:22:38.411+05:30  WARN 15340 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageController' defined in file [/Users/rohitkumar/Documents/projects/PeerMessenger/target/classes/com/peermessenger/controller/MessageController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'messageService' defined in file [/Users/rohitkumar/Documents/projects/PeerMessenger/target/classes/com/peermessenger/service/MessageService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.peermessenger.repository.MessageRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2023-12-24T17:22:38.412+05:30  INFO 15340 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.peermessenger.repository.MessageRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.peermessenger.service.MessageService required a bean of type 'com.peermessenger.repository.MessageRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.peermessenger.repository.MessageRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My Application file looks like:

```
package com.peermessenger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PeerMessengerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PeerMessengerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

MessageRepository:

```
package com.peermessenger.repository;

import com.peermessenger.model.Message;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    List<Message> findByReceiverId(Long receiverId);
    @Query("SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.receiver.username = :receiverUsername AND m.read = false")
    List<Message> findUnreadMessagesForUser(@Param("receiverUsername") String receiverUsername);
}
```

Comment: It looks Spring context doesn't find the MessageRepository bean. Your project compiles and build successfully or not?

Comment: can you also add Message entity as update of question and  pom.xml file ?

Comment: You must add `@EnableJpaRepositories` to your spring configuration.

Comment: I added ```@ComponentScan("com.peermessenger.repository")``` in the application driver class and it worked.

Comment: Please provide project structure screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added @ComponentScan("com.peermessenger.repository") in the application driver class and it worked.